# how to define a function?

Tags: functions, relations

If we define a function by set theory it states that it is relation in the sets of inputs and outputs such that each input is exactly related to one out put .
 so if 
$A=\{9,25,36\} ;\,  B=\{3,5,6\}$
and a relation 
 $R=\{(x,y)|\pm\sqrt{x}=y\,\land \,x\in A,\,y\in B\}$ also a function because it has exactly one element in $B$ for $A$ .
But if we define a function without set theory it states that a function produces one output for every input then the above mentioned relation is not a function .
so which is right and why ? please explain it .

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$ — see [How can I format mathematics here?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: Why is there a +/- in front of the square root? The minus produces values for $y$ that are not in $B$

Comment: it means the both +and- square roots of x .suppose x=4 then 2 and -2 by squaring produce 4 .

Comment: For clarification, if you're defining a function without set theory, what are you defining it in? And what is the "it" in "But if we define a function without set theory **it** states that..."?

Answer (score 0):

See more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)

A function is defined by an input-output relation; there must exist an **ordered pair** for $(x,y) \in X \times Y$.

Moreover, your relation is not a function because of the $+/-$ sign in front of $\sqrt{x}$; assuming one substitutes a certain value of $x$ one can get two different values for $y$.